# OO design for Tic Tac Toe program

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, design-patterns, tic-tac-toe

I am practicing object oriented design and have taken Tic Tac Toe as an example. I have written first all the requirements and then started writing code. I would like to get it reviewed so that I can improve my skill further. Please provide suggestions.

I have placed code at this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/coder3290/TicTacToe/tree/master/js).

**Square.js**

```
//Square class
function Square(){
    this.symbol = "";
    this.isOccupied = false;
}

//Based on player turn set symbols
Square.prototype.setSymbol = function(value){
    if(value !== 'X' && value !== 'O'){
        return 'Please enter X or O';
    }else if(this.isOccupied){
        return 'This square is already filler'
    }else{
        this.symbol = value;
        this.isOccupied = true;
    }
};

Square.prototype.getSymbol = function(){
    return this.symbol;
};
```

**Board.js**

```
//Board Class
function Board(sqaures){
    this.squares = sqaures;
    this.grid = [];
    this.filledSquare = 0;
}

//Builds board based on number of squares
Board.prototype.buildBoard = function(){
    var i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < this.squares; i++){
        this.grid[i] = [];
        for(j = 0; j < this.squares; j++){
            this.grid[i][j] = new Square();
        }
    }
};

//Updates board on each players turn
Board.prototype.update = function(row, column, symbol){
    this.grid[row][column].setSymbol(symbol);
    this.filledSquare++;
};

//Show the current state of board
Board.prototype.displayBoard = function(){
    var i, j,brd = "";
    for(i = 0; i < this.squares; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < this.squares; j++){
            brd += this.grid[i][j].getSymbol() +' - ';
        }
        brd += '\n';
    }
    console.log(brd);
};
```

**Player.js**

```
//Player Class
function Player(name,symbol){
    this.name = name;
    this.symbol = symbol;
}
```

**tttgame.js**

```
//The game class which governs the play
function TTTGame(squares){
    this.board = new Board(squares);
    this.board.buildBoard();
    this.players = [];
    this.players[0] = new Player('John','X');
    this.players[1] = new Player('Doe', 'O');

    this.getCurrentPlayer = function(){
        return (this.board.filledSquare %2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'O');
    };

    //I have written this as dummy method which should be replaced with actual logic
    this.play = function(){
        this.board.displayBoard();
        var currentPlayer = this.getCurrentPlayer();
        var row, col, symbol;
        this.board.update(0,1,currentPlayer);
        currentPlayer = this.getCurrentPlayer();
        this.board.update(0,0,currentPlayer);
        currentPlayer = this.getCurrentPlayer();
        this.board.update(1,1,currentPlayer);
        currentPlayer = this.getCurrentPlayer();
        this.board.update(2,1,currentPlayer);
        currentPlayer = this.getCurrentPlayer();
        this.board.update(1,0,currentPlayer);
        this.board.displayBoard();
    }

    //It will contain method to decide winner or tie
}
```

**GameStarter.js**

```
//Starts the game
(function GameStarter(){
    var tttGame = new TTTGame(3);
    tttGame.play();
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

Overall this looks pretty good. Just a couple of things come to mind:

**Square.js**

1. The `setSymbol` method should throw errors instead of returning strings, especially since I don't see any place where those strings are handled in a manner allowing the user to correct their mistake.
2. The error message when the square is occupied just needs a slight grammatical correction: `This square is already filled` (filled instead of filler)

**TTTGame.js**

1. Create all methods on the prototype. You aren't using any private function scope variables, so putting the methods on the prototype will be more efficient.

**General Comments**

The name `TTTGame` is kind of obtuse. I know it is probably an abbreviation for "Tick Tack Toe Game" but I think a more descriptive name is in order. All around, throwing these classes into a namespace would be useful. Consider the semantic differences between these two sets of classes:

- `Square` (is it a tick tack toe square or a two dimensional representation of a plane in mathematics)
- `Board` (Diving board? Game board? Discussion board?)
- `TTTGame` (What does TTT stand for?)

Vs:

- `TickTackToe.Square`
- `TickTackToe.Board`
- `TickTackToe.Game`

No explanation necessary for the second set of class names.

All in all, this looks pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting,

from a once over:

- You seem to do double data maintenance in Square, you can always tell from the value of symbol whether the place is occupied or not, so I would make `isOccupied` a function.

  ```
  //Square class
  function Square(){
      this.symbol;
  }

  Square.prototoype.isOccupied(){
      return this.symbol ? true : false;
  }
  ```

  This should also make `setSymbol` a bit easier
- The code in `setSymbol` seems a bit paranoid, not trusting the input and throwing unhandled strings when the input is not 'X' or 'O'. Since you leave the player symbol open-ended, I would leave this part open-ended as well and just allow `square.symbol = ..` since you no longer have to set `isOccupied`.
- This:

  ```
  Square.prototype.getSymbol = function(){
      return this.symbol;
  };
  ```

  has little value, why would you not provide direct access to `symbol`? Especially since you have no similar getter for `isOccupied`.
- `sqaures` -> `squares` (actually I would call this `size`, since `size` 3 will give 9 `squares`..)
- `filledSquare` -> `filledSquares`
- `brd` -> `board` and unless you are going for a Node.js tic-tac-toe, I would focus on getting an HTML output instead of `console.log`.
- From a high level perspective ( especially once you start checking for winning conditions ) you are several times looping over all squares. It could be convenient to be able to pass a function to a function which will apply the provided function to all squares.
- This make `Player`having a symbol a bit moot:

  ```
  this.getCurrentPlayer = function(){
      return (this.board.filledSquare %2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'O');
  };
  ```

  How about

  ```
  this.getCurrentPlayer = function(){
      return this.players[ this.board.filledSquare %2 ];
  };
  ```
- `var row, col, symbol;` <- Wot ?

All, in all, this looks like a good start, but you still have a ways to go.